# 2D mmorpg platformer should it be ptp?

Tags: software-design

I am currently developing an mmorpg. It will be a live action game. 
I need players to see each other in real time while walking and fighting. 
Now I have a big question. 
Should I make the connection to be PTP (player to player/peer to peer) or should it be player to server and server to players?

It will of course have a TCP connection to the server anyway in order to process important things like "trades", map switchings, etc...

However I am talking about the current position and animation of the players.
Should all that be sent directly to the other players? Have the server choose a player with good connection and make him to host the current "map"?

Sorry if this question is not to topic, I am new here.

Comment: You would have a better time in [gamedev.stackexchange](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/).   These types of question are basically the reason that SE exists.

Comment: Oh, sorry about that, thanks!

Comment: No worries, this technically isn't off-topic here, it might violate being to vague of question for Stack overflow though.  You are probably going to get way more help over there regardless.